# Accessing objects by name stored in a List

Tags: r

I am trying to solve this:
I have n matrices of different dimensions stored in a List. And, I have a n×1 matrix of n different strings(names).

I want to rename each matrix of the list with names stored in the matrix, so that I can access each object by name.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Anything you've already tried? Hint: look at `?names`. Anything else is hard to answer without a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`names(your_list) = your_matrix[ , 'matrix_col_name']`

Comment: Thanks, @Hillary! It helps. And just by using 'attach(my_list)' I am able to extract objects by name.